# Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist while uploading flask app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my flask app in AWS EB. I have just 2 files - application.py and requirements.txt. I have zipped them and uploaded via the EB Console.

And I get the following error:

Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.

In the configuration section my WSGI path is declared as application.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. The zip file had another folder inside it which had both the files. 
While deploying the zip file should have the application.py file.